# django_nose ignores wrapped tests

Tags: python, django, django-nose

I have such kind of wrapper

```
def external_services_mock(f):
    @patch('service.remote_call1')
    @patch('service.remote_call2')
    def wrapper(self, remote_call2_mock, remote_call1_mock, *args, **kwargs):
        remote_call1_mock.return_value = None

        def test_mocks():
            return remote_call1_mock, remote_call2_mock

        f(self, test_mocks, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

and test:

```
@external_services_mock
def test_add_callback(self, test_mocks):
    remote_call1_mock, remote_call2_mock = test_mocks()

    // do smth

    // assert smth
```

django_nose runner ignores wrapped tests, and normally runs regular

Django version 2.0.2
django_nose 1.4.5

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `functools.wraps` to preserve the name of the wrapped test seems to fix.

```py
from functools import wraps

def external_services_mock(f):
    @patch('service.remote_call1')
    @patch('service.remote_call2')
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, remote_call2_mock, remote_call1_mock, *args, **kwargs):
        remote_call1_mock.return_value = None

        def test_mocks():
            return remote_call1_mock, remote_call2_mock

        f(self, test_mocks, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```